# In Dart: How can I convert native to html formatted string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a native string to **UTF-8** with **HTML** format. For example, I want to convert the string `QQ登录` to `QQ&#x 767B;&#x 5F55;`. How can I achieve this?

I tried: `htmlEscape` and `Uri.dataFromString` these two interfaces, but neither worked.

Any answer is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried HtmlEnhancedEditor package from pub.dev?

Comment: Thanks，I will try HtmlEnhancedEditor:)